# Express: How to create functions outside of app.get()?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, global-functions

Something like this doesn't work for me:

```
function renderSite1() {
    return res.render('site.html');
}

app.get('/overview', function(req, res) {
    renderSite1();
}
```

How can I keep the routes clean and load function from outside?

Answer (score 4):

You can use it like this:

app.js

```
var campgroundRoutes      = require("./routes/campgrounds"),
    commentsRoutes        = require("./routes/comments"),
    indexRoutes            = require("./routes/index");

app.use(indexRoutes);
app.use("/campgrounds" , campgroundRoutes);
app.use("/campgrounds/:id/comments" , commentsRoutes);
```

index.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                               HOMEPAGE
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

router.get("/" , function(req,res){
    res.render("landing");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Id does not work because the scope of `res`, is the overview middleware, but render inherit the global scope which does not have the `res` declared.

What you can do is to pass req as parameter for renderSite1(), but this is not always clean.

What I enjoy to do is:

> Create a function which returns a new function with the req fixed

```
function renderModule(res) { // it will be fixed for all the functions
   function renderSite1() {
     res.render() // visible
   }

   function renderSite2() {
     res.render() // visible
   }

   return {
     renderSite1,
     renderSite2
   }
}
```

This technique is called, **revealing module** pattern

What @artidokuz wrote in the answer is also a very good approach, divide your application using middlewares.